# bottom custom oh-my-zsh like statusbars for vim

Tags: vim, themes, oh-my-zsh

I saw this picture in one of the CodeSchool's Screencast. @GreggPollack has customised his vim to look like one in the bottom picture.

[image]

I really like this bottom strip and that syntax highlighting for insert and other stuff on bottom command strip. I have the same strips for $prompts for my terminal with oh-my-zsh agnoster theme. How would I do that for vim?

Comment: Why don't you ask him directly?

Comment: @romainl How? I see he is not an active user on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/users/578657/gregg-pollack

Comment: There's a huge world beyond SO, you know? You can send him an email, a tweet…

Comment: Ok I will try get in touch with him. I will post the answer here once I get a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "bottom strip" is called statusline and its customization options are described in the following help page [`:help 'statusline'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27statusline%27).

But most people prefer to use plugins for this purpose, which already include extensions that automatically fill in the statusline with extra information related with the currently opened file. The information displayed typically depend on the plugins under use.

The two most famous plugins for statusline configuration are:

- [Powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline)
- [Airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline)